# OnClick() Android Issue

Tags: android

Im really getting lost using the whole CountDownTimer my aim is too simply restart the timer when the user presses a button, but near the onClick method it displays a warning saying "The method onClick from the type CountDownTimer is never used locally. If anyone realises where im going wrong guide me please! :)

```
    Counter = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            TextView timeShow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
    timeShow.setText(" "+" 00:" +millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }


        public void onClick(View v) { 
            switch(v.getId()){  

            case R.id.keypad_0:
                if(Counter !=null){
            Counter.cancel(); 
                }
        } 
    }; 

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


 }.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the CountDownTimer doesn't actually have an onClick event.

You will want to put that onClick event handler in your Activity. (I am assuming you have a Button in your Activity layout XML that has an onClick attribute)

Also, I would change your [Count variable into lowercase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase#Programming_and_coding), because as it stands right now it looks like a Class.

Comment: Hm ok that makes sence so theoretically i can put a boolean on a onClick() and have it to Count.cancel() etc. When i do try that it doesnt pick up the Counter variable

Comment: Where are you declaring the count variable? If you want it to be accessible from the onClick event the easiest place to declare it would be as a Class member variable.